# Rendering HTML which includes javascript src file in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using expressJS in my nodeJS application. I am getting the following error while rendering (using sendFile) an html file containing js code src="../../viewer/something.js" to a browser from a route requested from a browser client:

The resource from “http://localhost:3000/viewer/something.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
Loading failed for the with source “http://localhost:3000/viewer/something.js”.

I even tried to define the Content-Type=“text/javascript” in the above  line of the HTML page.
How do I enable inclusion of the src file in the HTML files rendered from nodejs using sendFile? Can someone help please?

Comment: I guess this is to do with the file path not resolving more than the content type issue. Check if you can hit the JS file url from browser and that it can load

Comment: yes as mentioned below.

Answer (score 1):

You should set your static folder like this

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

Also, You'll need to give your HTML file the right path to your script file.

`<script src="/viewer/something.js"></script>`

Comment: I think that was it! Thanks a lot Vaibhav!

Comment: @prafull Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.